# QueryProjection with List as one of the parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I'm writing a query for the following domain model

```
@QueryEntity
public class Person
{
   ...
   private String name;
   private List<String> addresses;
   ...
}
```

And I wish to have the query result return to me a representation of a person as there are too much other fields that I do no care about.

```
public class PersonRepresentation
{
    private string name;
    private List<String> addresses;

    @QueryProjection
    public PersonRepresentation(String name, List<String> addresses){
        this.name = name;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I attempt to create my JPA query as such

```
private final QPersonRepresentation qPersonRepresentationProjection = new QPersonRepresentation(
                qPerson.name,
                qPerson.addresses
        );

    List<PersonRepresentation> result = new JPAQuery(em)
                    .from(qPerson)
                    .list(qPersonRepresentationProjection);
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: not
>   an entity [select person.name,
>   person.addresses from
>   com.example.foo.Person person]
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> ....

I've scurred both the documentation and the tests on the github and so far cannot come up with a reason why I cannot execute this query.

Comment: why you create another class instead of annotating the contructor directly into Person entity?

Comment: Because I do not wish to use the domain object as a representation that i am returning somewhere else. This representation will be lighter weight as it has less fields then Person